# Could someone help me understand how to solve these types of equations. I don't know how to solve them?

Tags: logarithms

Could someone help me understand how to solve these types of equations. I don't know how to solve them?

> a. 1+5e<sup>1+3x</sup>=6
>
> b. 3log(1-2z)+1=7
>
> c.log<sub>3</sub>(x-4)+log<sub>3</sub>(x+4)=3
>
> d. log<sub>5</sub>(2x-1)-log<sub>5</sub>(x-4)=2
>
> e. ln(2t+1)+ln(2t-1)=0

It says also no decimal answers will be excepted for the assignment.

Comment: Try to solve the first. I'll help you.

Comment: I hope it says decimal answers will not be accepted for the assignment, but that is an English topic.  You need to study the laws of logarithms, particularly the ones that change sums and differences of logs into logs of products or fractions for c,d,e.  For a,b you need to look at the definition of log in terms of exponentials.

Answer (score 1):

You solve them the same way as any other.  You isolate the $x$ by "unwrapping" by doing the opposite  step by step.

$1+5e^{1+3x}=6$  First we unwrap the "$1+$" by doing the opposite.  The oppposite is $-1$

$5e^{1+3x} = 6-1 = 5$.  Then we unwrap the "multiply by $5$" by doing the opposite.  The opposite of multiply by $5$ is divide by five.

$\frac {5e^{1+3x}}5 = \frac 55$

$e^{1+3x} = 1$.  THen we unwrap the "$e^{whatever}$" by doing the opposite.  The opposite of $e^{whatever}$ is to take the natural log.

$\ln e^{1+3x} =  \ln 1$.

$1+3x = 0$  Now we unwrap the $1+$

$3x = 0 -1 = -1$.  Now we unwrap the "times $3$".

$\frac {3x}3 = \frac {-1}{3}$

$x = \frac {-1}{3}$.

... and to verify:

$1 + 5e^{1 + 3(\frac {-1}3)} = 1 + 5e^{1-1} = 1 + 5e^0 = 1+5*1 = 1+5 = 6$.

Answer (score 0):

Log to the base "e" is the Same as national logarithm(ln). To bring an exponent to a base,you have to take Logarithm of both sides. Also apply the definition of logarithm and it's properties in addition(meaning you have to multiply them) and subtraction(meaning you have to divide them). I think that solves your question

Comment: First time I hear about *national logarithm* !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Lucky me not drinking coffee while reading about *national logarithm* so I don't have to buy a new screen :))